# why my flask app didnt connect to the cloud firestore? I wrote this code

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-firestore

When i run my script to conect my database to the cloudfirestore, it doesnt throws errors but it doesnt create any collection that I specify. can you help me to fix my code logic errors. thanks.

```
def get_db():
"""
This is my database engine to cloud firestore
"""

if 'db' not in g:
    cred = credentials.Certificate("key.json")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
    g.db = firestore.client()


return g.db

def init_db():
   """
   Function that creates all collections
   """
   db = get_db()

   for collection in collectionsName:
       db.collection(collection)


@click.command("init-db")
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
   """
   I initialize db with command 'init-db'
   """
   init_db()
   click.echo("base de datos inicializada")

def init_app(app):
   """
   run my flask app and connect to my cloud firestore db
   """

   app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

this how i run the script : flask init-db

my flask **init**.py look like this

```
  def create_app():
      app = Flask(__name__)

      from . import db
      db.init_app(app)


      return app
```

Comment: What makes you think it didn’t connect? Did it throw an error? What is it and what line did it happen on?

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in question's title.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Please provide more information about the issue you are facing by posting the error you received and the documentation you followed

Comment: It doesn't throws any error but when I try to create a collection in cloud Firestore, doesn't appears anything

Comment: i think there is a logic error not a syntaxis error, and im sorry this is my first time in stack overflow but ill imprve the way I ask questions

Comment: How are you running this code? How are you running any of those functions? Your posted code just declares functions, but no code posted that calls them. You also said Flask app, but there is no Flask anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

To initialize a collection, create at least one document in the collection. For example:

```
def init_db():
   """
   Function that creates all collections
   """
   db = get_db()
   # for each collection, create an initial doc
   for collection in collectionsName:
       db.collection(collection).document('init_coll').set({'exists': True})
```